# How to define a variable from a line of a file in C

Tags: c, file, variables, input, output

So I've got a thing that writes stuff in a file. Got some pseudocode as well. I just need to define floats for each line of a file called config.txt. EG: reading from the file.

```
else
{
    //pseudocode for inputting 6 the six variables
    FILE *file
    file = fopen("config.txt","a+");
    fscanf(file,"%s",
    float dollarToYen == l1;
    float dollarToPound == l2;
    float dollarToEuro == l3;
    float yenToPound == l4;
    float yenToEuro == l5;
    float poundToEuro == l6;
}
```

How do I make the floats be what's on the lines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `%f %f %f %f %f %f`  and `&dollarToYen`, `&dollarToPound`....., but as per your peoblem statemment, it looked more like `fprintf()`.

Comment: and don't forget to refer the manual pages for proper syntax.

Comment: I think you're actually looking for [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write in the file.

```
else
    {
        FILE *file
        file = fopen("config.txt","a+");
        fprintf(file,"%f %f %f %f %f %f",l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6);
    }
```

Please make your question more clear. You can edit your question or commen.